# How do I display Google Maps in Filemaker webdirect?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, filemaker

I'm trying to show google maps on Filemaker webdirect (FM 14). I can get Google static maps to show, but nothing in webdirect. I have the Google maps API, also can't get that to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It’s most likely due to the fact that FileMaker renders WebDirect Web Viewers in iframes and not all Google map APIs support that. Try the [embed API.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/)

Edit: This comment on a forum post in the FileMaker Developer community should give you further info. https://community.filemaker.com/thread/176826#comment-687336